# What is the generating function to calculate the number of functions $f:\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}\to\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ with $|Im(f)|=4$?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

What is the generating function to calculate the number of functions 
$f:\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}\to\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ with $|Im(f)|=4$?

I've tried these:

- $$\sum_{k=1}^{10}x^k \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{7}x^k$$
- $$\sum_{k=1}^{10}x^k \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{7}y^k$$
- $$\sum_{k=1}^{10}ax^k \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{7}bx^k$$
- $$\sum_{k=1}^{10}a_k x^k \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{7}b_k x^k$$

But upon thinking about them, their coefficients and exponents didn't seem too revealing. Perhaps I made some kind of mistake and one of these actually solve the problem, but I can't see it. I know there is a way to do it via inclusion-exclusion, but I'm deeply interested in the generating function of it.

Comment: You're asking for the generating function of **a constant**? What does that mean?

Comment: The number of functions $f:[10]\to[7]$ with $|Im f|=4$ is a constant; it's 28,648,200 if I did the calculation right, but anyway it's a constant. What is the generating function of $28,648,200$? I **guess** you're thinking of some generalized problem, e.g., let $a_{m,n,p}$ be the number of functions $f:[m]\to[n]$ with $|Im f|=p$; in that case the generating function would be a function of three variables. Is that what you're after??

Comment: @bof See Jack's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of such functions is $${10 \brace 4}\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4$$
where ${10 \brace 4}$ a [Stirling number of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html), counting in how many ways it is possible to partition a $10$ elements set into four nonempty subsets. Inclusion-exclusion principle gives:
$${n \brace k}=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^i\binom{k}{i}(k-i)^n $$
and the EGF for Stirling numbers of the second kind is:
$$\sum_{n=k}^{+\infty}{n \brace k}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac{1}{k!}(e^x-1)^k$$
while the OGF is:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{n \brace k}x^n = \frac{x^k}{(1-x)(1-2x)\cdot\ldots\cdot(1-kx)}.$$

Comment: This might be a silly question, but: Is it generally possible to express the same thing with both OGP's and EGF's?

Comment: @Vÿska: this is a pretty lucky case, it is quite rare that for a certain combinatorial sequence $\{a_n\}$ both the OGF and the EGF have nice closed expressions.

Comment: But anything that is expressed with one could also be expressed with the other, right? Disregarding if they have good closed expressions.

Comment: @Vÿska: yes. Both the EGF and the OGF come from the identity: $${n+1\brace k}=k{n \brace k}+{n \brace k-1}.$$